# If A is finite, then P(A) is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am solving the following exercise from Munkres. I was able to prove part (a) by the use of indicator function I proved that $\phi : P(A) \rightarrow X^n$, where $\phi(B) = I_B$. Here $I_B$ is the indicator function for the subset B.  It is easy to show that such a function is a bijection.

I am little bit confused on the second part of the question. First I was thinking of showing that $|P(A)| = 2^{|{A}|}$ using combinatorics, but then I am confused how can I get a explicit bijection between $P(A)$ and $\{1,...,2^A\}$?

> $\rm(a)$ Let $A=\{1,...,n\}$. Show there is a bijection of ${\scr P}(A)$ with the cartesian product $X^n$, where $X$ is the two-element set $X=\{0,1\}$.
>   $\rm(b)$ Show that if $A$ is finite, then ${\scr P}(A)$ is finite.

Comment: For part a) instead of thinking of the set $\{1,2,\dots,2^{|A|}\}$, think of using the set $\{000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111\}$ in the case of $|A|=3$ and similarly the set of all binary strings of length $n$ for $|A|=n$.  By temporarily assigning an arbitrary order on the set $A$, we can construct a bijection where the $i$'th digit is zero iff the $i$'th element of $A$ is in the set in question and one otherwise.  Now, taking *this* set, you can if you like make a bijection to $\{1,2,3,\dots,2^{|A|}\}$ using binary representation of the numbers.

Comment: $001\mapsto 1, 010\mapsto 2, 011\mapsto 3, 100\mapsto 4$ et cetera.  And then, $000\mapsto 2^{|A|}$ is the only exception.  Alternatively, you could have $000\mapsto 1, 001\mapsto 2$ et cetera.

Comment: Part (b) follows immeidately from part (b): $|\{0, 1\}^n| = |\{0, 1\}|^n = 2^n$. (If you want an explicit bijection, consider an element of $\{0, 1\}^n$ as a binary string, then unravel the bijection in part (a)).

Comment: @anomaly I suggest you post this as an answer.

Comment: @Stefan: Sure, very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (b) follows immediately from part (a): $|\{0, 1\}^n| = |\{0, 1\}|^n = 2^n$. (If you want an explicit bijection--- which is probably not the best way of doing this problem--- then consider an element of $\{0, 1\}^n$ as a binary string and unravel the bijection in part (a).)

Comment: Yeah I thought of for part (a) using indicator function, but I should have continued on this idea for part (b). Brilliant thank you!

Comment: No thanks are necessary, but you're welcome.